# How to install Prophet package in R

Tags: r

I'm using "R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) on databricks. I'm trying to install prophet package in R. So I wrote following command

```
install.packages('prophet')
```

But I'm getting error message

```
[Fetched stdout timeout]
```

My R studio with R Version 4.02 is showing message

```
 Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances 
 License License_is_FOSS
 License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built
```

and

```
library(prophet)
```

is not working in R studio too
Can you suggest me how do I install prophet?

Comment: Is that the only thing that prints out? Is there no more to the message? Are you sure you have a working internet connection? What does `options("repos")` return?

Comment: Yes, that was the only things prints out. `options("repos")` is giving `$repos
                         Cloud                           MRAN 
"https://cloud.r-project.org/"  "https://cran.microsoft.com/" `

Comment: Sounds like internet trouble. Can you connect to https://cloud.r-project.org/ in your browser?

Comment: I can able to connect

Comment: In R studio with R 4.0.2 version I'm getting message  Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances 
 License License_is_FOSS
 License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built & library('prophet') is showing  there is no package called ‘prophet’